# Modify an Angular factory after it has been created?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ngResource factory that is created as such:

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .factory("versionResource", versionResource);

function versionResource($resource) {
    return $resource("api/versions/:versionId",
        {
            versionId: "@versionId"
        }
    );
}
```

This code is automatically generated for me. I would like to extent the version Resource so that there is a `.create` function on it. This could be done by modifying the code to this:

```
function versionResource($resource) {
    return $resource("api/versions/:versionId",
        {
            versionId: "@versionId"
        },
        {
            create: {
                method: "POST",
                url: "api/versions/create"
            }
        }
    );
}
```

However, because the initial code is automatically generated, it will get overwritten from time to time. I would like to extend the factory somehow. Something like:

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .run(run);

function run(versionResource) {
    versionResource.create = {
                method: "POST",
                url: "api/versions/create"
            };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) may be useful. See the example below:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.config(['$provide', function($provide) {

  $provide.decorator('$resource', ['$delegate',
    function myServiceDecorator($delegate) {
      return function decoratedResource() {
        var url = arguments[0].split('/').slice(0,2).join('/');
        arguments[2].create = {
          method: "POST",
          url: url + "/create"
        };
        return $delegate.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    }
  ]);

}]);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kursadgulseven/gjLcav4y/) is a working fiddle. Open developer tools network tab and run it. You will see successful create post.

Comment: That's not going to get me a valid method/function on the ngResource instance, though. When passing in an additional action to the ngResource constructor, it calls `actions = extend({}, provider.defaults.actions, actions);` and then extracts the parameters, etc. That's really what I'm asking - there's no way to easily convert the `create` object into a `create` method, after instantiating?

Comment: I was out for lunch. I had time to update my answer; please check.